# Filtering data and Display Heading based on filters

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

being a newbie to SSRS, I am trying to figure out the following:

say for instance I have a dataset which does a :

```
SELECT [cols...] from [some view]
```

I want to be able to further filter this based on parameters given from an ASP.NET site (I am using the AJAX control toolkit for the report viewer). There could be x amount of parameters and potentially can be filtered on 1 or more columns.

First question is, how would I filter the dataset and pass along the parameters along with which field the filter should apply to? I may have [col1] and I want to filter it with x values.

Second question Is, I want to be able to group the results per page based upon a column. So for each grouped result set, I want them to be displayed per page (per group per page).
Then on the headers of the page, I want it to display what the page grouping is. How would I do this?

In terms of what have I tried - nothing as **I DO NOT KNOW HOW**, it is why I am asking the question here to see what the experts (you) can suggest and guide me.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can create Parameters in SSRS, they do not need to be in your query or anything. Then, go to your tablix and click either ROW or column depending on the filter type and set it show/hide visibility. For example I have a report that has personal information, so i have true/false parameter that hides/shows those columns, similar I have one that hides/shows any row with a -1 for the total paid.

Comment: So what about for doing the filtering on the datasource? Since I am using (for now) local reporting, I suspect I need to extract the CommandText in the RDL file and then append the filtering? if it was a Remote reporting then how would I filter that datasource with parameters along with the columns I wish to filter?

Comment: Are you talking about something other than adding parameters to your query? that tie to the parameters in the reporting portal ?

Comment: nope - purely talking about the filtering of the datasource by accepting the parameters from the user interface on the ASP.NET website. Just wondering how to set up the report to take those parameters (if supplied) and apply them.

Comment: Alright, I know for anything I have done  i just treat the query like always with paramenters, and then go into the data set properties and assign the Parameter i want to match up with those in the query, then SSRS does the rest i will resign to someone else :)